# How to attach a python file to each row(i.e. each data entry) in database formed using Django?

Tags: python, django

Ive used default django superuser to create an admin and created a DB using it. But now in that i want to add a python script to each data entry i.e. row. How do i do this???

Nothing special. Used basic Django.

Comment: What does that mean? What would "attaching" a script to a row involve? What would you do with that script?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I would be running that script whenever an API occurs (by compairing the value of the first column and then running the respective py script according to it) First column will be used to identify which py script to run.The pyscript will return a json object and then i'll send it back as a reply to the api. Can I do this?

Comment: Where are those scripts coming from? Are they uploaded by the user, or are they already part of your codebase?

Comment: Part of the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything particularly complex here. You're just asking if you can use a field on the model to choose something; of course you can.

For instance:

```
# actions.py
def thing1(obj):
   # do something with obj

def thing2(obj):
   # do something else with obj


# models.py
from . import actions

ACTIONS = {
    "do_thing_1": actions.thing1,
    "do_thing_2": actions.thing2,
}
ACTION_CHOICES = [(action, action) for action in ACTIONS]

class MyModel(models.Model):
    action = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ACTION_CHOICES)

    def do_action(self):
        return ACTIONS[self.action](self)
```

Comment: No, actually i want the field to be returning a json file only on API request i.e. not performing action rather sending the file only when api is obtained.